# BASH: Is it possible to multi-thread a function within a single BASH script? If so, how?

Tags: bash, multithreading, function, background, multiprocessing

In my use case, I've got a single-threaded backup script where I know from other experience the hardware can handle around 30X the I/O bandwidth, and single-threaded it's taking so long to complete it's still running into the morning work period.

The trouble is, just backgrounding the individual I/O bound commands doesn't work because there's follow-on tasks that depend on previous task's results. Most importantly, if `rsync` reports no updates, skip creating a formal backup file (such as `zip` or `tar`), plus a tiny bit of reporting on the matter. There are other cases of order dependency but getting `rsync` results before moving on in that set of commands is vital.

In the past I've just multi-processed by kicking off a companion script but over time this has proven problematic as editing multiple scripts becomes error-prone as times change and needs shift. So, I'd like to keep it all in one script.

I've noticed that functions can have, according to my read of the documentation anyway, redirected input and output, and that got me thinking about the use of a function or braces grouping and related mechanisms; perhaps there's a way to group these related commands and then background the lot of them?

If so, this would be a "cheap" way of multi-threading a BASH script but even as I type this I'm thinking NO?! It's ONE BASH instance?! However, I know I'm ignorant about many wonderful features of BASH, so maybe?

Note that I've considered tracking pids, and it's on the one hand conceptually straight-forward, but on the other, non-trivial on its own because of the follow-on I/O bound task using the same context (set of arguments). ...If that's what I'd have to do, ... arrays and so forth would be in my future, matching up arguments with pids! ... I might just keep on using a companion script, OR consider writing a short script on the fly in temporary files?! -ugh!- Not looking forward to that, either.

Is there another way?

Comment: It sounds like you want `f() { cmd1; cmd2; } ; f &`? Put the pipeline in a function and background it. If not maybe try creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us where you're getting stuck so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: @tjm3772 Thanks ... I get the function part of your sample code, but I'm not sure I've fully got the follow-on; you're just saying after your function you call it with a backgrounding?! YES, that's what I'm wondering if it's even possible! Does that work? If that's not what you meant, then, please clarify!

Comment: once you background a script/function (see tjm3772's example) it becomes a brand new (OS-level) process and loses any association (memory wise) with the parent, so now you have to choose from an assortment of interprocess communications (eg, files, sockets, shared memory, queuing system, a database, etc); imo the 'easiest' to implement would be files, preferably a separate file for each backgrounded process to eliminate the need for locking (to keep multiple pids from overwriting/scrambling data); have the parent create the (tmp) files and make sure each child is told which file to use

Comment: @markp-fuso THANK YOU for clarifying! Happily, I can fairly easily pass all that's needed for context to one function as arguments. ... If it's a true fork, then it carries with it all the context of the past up to that point, right? If so, then I don't need any of that interprocess communcation, however, it's GREAT to bring that up! ...I've already tried it on a sample run - all I really had to do was remove and add a few & characters! Looks to be working "as we speak." ;-) While this isn't a "real run" (that'll come tomorrow AM) looks OK. Maybe someone ought write this up as an answer?!

Comment: the interprocess comms would be required if the parent needs to access something that the child generates (eg, feedback, error/return codes, data to feed to follow-on child process, etc); if a backgrounded/child process is truly a fire-n-forget type of operation then yeah, no need for interprocess comms; as for writing up an answer ... there are a handful of options depending on your (not 100% clear to me) requirements, so a viable answer will likely ramble on a bit too much ... my suggestion ... write up your own answer with details of what works for you

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to have the script call itself and check whether it's the parent process or the child. I've given an example below. If you save this as something like `mybackup.sh` and run it with `./mybackup.sh this that tother` you can hopefully see how it works.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

backupdir="$@"
script_name="$0"
base_name=$(basename ${script_name})

# This will be the name of your shell for the parent process
# but the name of the script itself if it's a child process
if [[ $(ps -o comm= $PPID) != "${base_name}" ]]; then
  echo "Parent process"

  # Export a variable to pass it to the child process
  export childvalue="something_to_pass_to_child_process"

  # Run this same script for each directory in our list
  for dir in ${backupdir}; do
    ${script_name} ${dir} &
  done

  wait # wait for all child processes to return
  echo "Do general stuff after all backups are completed"

else
  echo "Child process with ${backupdir}"
  echo "Value is: ${childvalue}"
  # do some rsync stuff or whatever
  # I'll just sleep instead so you can see it work
  sleep $(($RANDOM % 7))
  echo "${backupdir} complete"
fi

# End of script
exit 0
```

Comment: Yes, I've used recursion many times; a genuine fork (see comments to my question) is another, even easier way to do it that happens to fit my use-case perfectly. However, maybe there are others for whom your solution is a better answer? IDK. However, recursion DOES address one issue I have with having multipe scripts, namely, having to update TWO locations when needs shift. That has proven, in my experience, to not be a great plan.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by tjm3772 in the first comment to my question, the answer to my question is YES; you CAN background a function and, apparently, any set of BASH commands you put inside curly braces, { and }.

And, as noted by the second commenter, markp-fuso, this effectively forks the running code, thus making it it's own process, and that's how it "multi-threads," by actually multi-processing. So this is, in fact, " a 'cheap' way of multi-threading a BASH script," as I suspected might be possible and suggested in my question.

**Importantly...**

Note that this **only** works without further complications, as markp-fuso pointed out, if the backgrounded tasks don't need to share any of the results with the "parent" process. This is because the process is forked, and thus it no longer shares context; the variables are no longer shared.

Thus, if the backgrounded tasks don't need to share any of the results with the "parent" process, it's fine. But otherwise, if further interchange is required, some other mechanism needs to be used and, well, it is no longer "cheap multi-tasking" in my view!

My first use of this technique has no such requirement and so, when the code ran last night, this reduced the run-time (elapsed "wall-clock" time) from around 9 to 10 hours to about 1 hour four minutes. Not bad!

My code is FAR too large and complex to post here, but as a partial "concrete example," in pseudo-code:

```
function run_rsync()
{
   source="$1"
   destination="$2"
   local syncLog=$(date +$logPath/%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N)
   rsync $rsync_flags "$source" "$destination" > "$syncLog"
   < ... parse log, note any changes found ... >
   if [ $syncCount -gt 0 ] ;
   then
      run_tar "$source"
   fi
}

function run_tar()
{
   source="$1"
   tmp=$(basename "$source")
   tFileName="$tar_dir/$tmp.tar"
   tar $tar_flags "$tFileName" "$source"
}

if [ -n $skip_sync ] ;
then
   run_tar "$source" &
else
   run_rsync "$source" "$destination" &
fi
```

I DO have some follow-on questions about the processes so created. For example, do they continue when the "parent" exits? At the moment, I have a 'wait' command that gets executed before exiting.

For another, I'm curious about redirecting the stdin and stdout of functions - this might well have some interesting applications! But these are also separate issues.